# can't open a specific workspace with the "File: Open Folder..." command

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't open one specific workspace which contains a python project.
After running the command, nothing happened.

the other workspaces can be got open with the command.

Could you please tell me how to solve this issue?

I connect all workspaces with ssh using the VScode ssh extension.

I saw this [related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85455), but it seems to be for a local environment.

I have checked what is happening in the Developer Tools console when I run the "File: Open Folder..." command.

the result in the Developer Tools console

[image: img]

Comment: The error message you shared has to do with JavaScript source maps. Your question appears to be about how to use Visual Studio Code, not about coding and not about Python.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful comments. I removed the python tag. I attached the javascript message from VScode because I couldn't see any message except it after running the "File: Open Folder..." command. This seems to be the only difference between correctly working workspaces and the not working workspace for now.